# Как в get_terms вывести сортировку в шаблоне

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста еще по одному вопросу. Есть код вывода таксономии:

```
    $ags = array(
         'taxonomy'   => 'label',
         'parent'  => '146',
        );          
         $terms = get_terms($ags);
             foreach($terms as $term){
             $zagolovok_glav = $term->name;
             echo $zagolovok_glav;
             }
```

А как вывести сортировку по **$zagolovok_glav**? Чтобы получилось вот так:

```
<select name="sorting" class="sorting_select">
    <option value="ASC">С начала алфавита</option>
    <option value="DESC">С конца алфавита</option>
</select>
```

Это возможно в get_terms?

Comment: Такую сортировку проще всего сделать на js: в зависимости от выбранного варианта просто менять порядок отображения элементов. Можно, конечно, и средствами wp делать сортировку, но тогда придётся каждый раз отправлять ajax-запрос на сервер с соответствующим параметром.

Comment: Я с js не дружу :) А в wp не знаю как сделать, даже зацепки нет)

Comment: ну да, проблема в том, что и ajax-запрос Вы без js не отправите :) так что придётся изучать

Comment: А есть примеры подобных выводов? Или примеры js? Как к get_terms присоединиться?

Comment: я набросал небольшой примерчик, самый простой - по сути переворачивание списка

Answer (score 2):

По идее `get_terms()` по умолчанию выводит данные в алфавитном порядке, но можно для верности добавить в `$ags` `'order' => 'ASC'`. А на стороне клиента при изменении значения `select` переворачивать список:

```js
let titles = ['Апельсины','Бананы','Груши','Дыни','Яблоки'];
let wrap = document.getElementById('wrapper');

titles.forEach((title) => wrap.innerHTML += `<span>${title}</span>`);

let sort = document.getElementById('sort');
sort.onchange = function() {
  wrap.classList.toggle('reverse');
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#wrapper.reverse {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<select name="sorting" class="sorting_select" id="sort">
    <option value="ASC">С начала алфавита</option>
    <option value="DESC">С конца алфавита</option>
</select>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Здесь должен выполняться Ваш php-код, я просто сымитировал вывод данных с помощью js. Обратите внимание, что $zagolovok_glav при выводе нужно обернуть в какой-нибудь элемент - span или div: у Вас сейчас просто echo $zagolovok_glav, а нужно echo '<span>'.$zagolovok_glav.'</span>' 
-->
</div>
```

**UPD**
Вот вариант с настоящей сортировкой, а не просто переворачиванием списка. Для простоты я элементы вписал в html - будем считать, что они уже пришли к нам на фронт в таком виде благодаря `get_terms()`:

```js
let wrap = document.getElementById('wrapper');
let sort = document.getElementById('sort');

let elems = document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper span');
let titles = [];

elems.forEach((el) => titles.push(el.outerText));

sort.onchange = function() {
  if(sort.value == 'ASC') {
    titles.sort();
  }
  else if(sort.value == 'DESC') {
    titles.sort().reverse();
  }
  else {
    titles = [];
    elems.forEach((el) => titles.push(el.outerText));
  }
  wrap.innerHTML = '';
  titles.forEach((title) => wrap.innerHTML += `<span>${title}</span>`);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<select name="sorting" class="sorting_select" id="sort">
    <option>По умолчанию</option>
    <option value="ASC">С начала алфавита</option>
    <option value="DESC">С конца алфавита</option>
</select>
<div id="wrapper">
  <span>Бананы</span>
  <span>Апельсины</span>
  <span>Яблоки</span>
  <span>Дыни</span>
  <span>Груши</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант, буду пробовать, только этот скрипт просто меняет местами список. У меня по умолчанию стоит вот так: `['Бананы','Апельсины','Яблоки','Дыни','Груши'];` Как сделать именно сортировку по алфавиту в обоих порядках?

Comment: @СветланаЗайцева, вот если Вы всё-таки последуете моему совету и изначально добавите в $ags 'order' => 'ASC', то список сразу будет выводиться в алфавитном порядке :) И тогда его будет достаточно просто переворачивать. Но если нужна более сложная сортировка, такое тоже возможно, чуть позже постараюсь добавить пример.

Comment: Так у меня весь смысл в том, что по умолчанию стоят приоритетные заголовки :) @humster_spb спасибо)

Comment: @СветланаЗайцева, добавил вариант с настоящей сортировкой

Comment: Можно только вместо "Вариант сортировки..." сделать "По умолчанию", чтобы возвращало в первоначальный список?

Comment: @СветланаЗайцева, можно :) Сделал